# separating result from mysql_fetch_array

Tags: php, mysql

Hy I have this code:

```
$query = "SELECT feed_url FROM url_store";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array ($result)) {
        echo $row[0];}}
```

The assigment of that code would be to get all fields from feed_url but separadted that I can get exp. link1, link2...

Comment: if I understand properly, you would want to change echo $row[0]; to echo $row['feed_url'];

Comment: no, I want that i get result1 for one link result2 for second link and so on...

Comment: -1 because your question not clear.

Comment: it is hard to explain...no problem :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not complete sure what you are looking for, but would could try this:

```
$query = "SELECT feed_url FROM url_store";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array ($result)) {
        echo "<a href='".$row['feed_url']."'>".$row['feed_url']."</a><br>";}
    }
```

If you provide more info, I might be able to provide you more help.

Comment: that is ok, but is it posslible that i get first one link, than i do some code for download rss from it than the secon link and the code for downloading rss from secodn one and so on...

Comment: Not sure, but do you mean you want the first link and then RSS section and then then second then third link and then RSS section and so on.

Comment: Is the RSS section link in the same table or database?

Comment: This is what i mean yes.

Comment: it is the same databse...one table is with links and the other is with news....I have to run a php script with cron job which will every day take all link from one table and take rss feeds from them and store feeds in another table

Comment: Could you provide me the tables (structure) and some sample data?

Comment: i can't give you but i can explain you detailed....so in one table there is a link from cnn, msn and other... and I have a script which downloads rss feeds from provided links....so in that script I want to make for loop which will take all rss feeds from cnn first, and than from msn...and so on depending how many are there in this table... so I would only like to save mysql_fetch_array in some array like row[i] that first time i is for cnn and second time i stands for msn... I hope it is more clear..

Comment: @Mateo how do you determine which RSS feed will below which link?

Comment: i store url in to database where are my feeds
and connection between two tables is not really important but that is easy to make...